# How to disable the replication from Solr Master for particular cores on all slaves?

Tags: solr, replication

I am aware that I can disable the replication from master for all slaves as follows:

http://master_host:port/solr/replication?command=disablereplication

However, as per my understanding, this disabling of replication is for all of the cores. Can we specify which core we do want to disable the replication for?

Please note that I do not want to use the replication disabling facility from slave side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of the core is missing in your command. I think if you add the core name then it should work. I found this command in [Solr Index Replication](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Index+Replication#IndexReplication-HTTPAPICommandsfortheReplicationHandler) documentation.

```
http://master_host:port/solr/core_name/replication?command=disablereplication
```

Also I think you can explore the Replication Screen for disabling the Replication from master side. This is also mentioned in [Solr Replication Screen](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Replication+Screen) documentation.

I hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Does this work in Solr 4 as well? The documentation that you provided seems to be an unreleased guide for Apache Solr 5.4

Comment: @genonymous This is also available in solr 4.10 documentation. Please check.